# Instantiation vs substitution in Smulyan's First order Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am learning logic by reading R.M. Smullyan's First Order logic. I have included images of the relevant pages below.

On page 44 he defines: a formula $A$ is closed if for every variable $x$ and every parameter $a$, $A_{a}^{x}=A$ (i.e. no variable has a free occurrence in $A$).

Then on page 47 he considers the set $E^{\cup}$ of all closed $\cup$-formulas and states that for every $A$ in $E^{\cup}$ and every variable $x$

1. $\nu$ is a Boolean valuation of $E^{\cup}$.
2. (a) $(\forall x)A$ is true under $\nu$ iff for every $k\in\cup$, $A_{k}^{x}$ is true under $\nu$.

This is what confuses me: Since $A\in E^{\cup}$ then $A$ is closed, which means that no variables occur freely in $A$, i.e. $A_{k}^{x}=A$. Also, since $A$ is closed $(\forall x)A$ is simply $A$. From this (a) appears to be: $A$ is true under $\nu$ iff $A$ is true under $\nu$.

On the other hand, (a) intuitively seems to mean that $(\forall x)A$ is true under $\nu$ when every instance of it in $\cup$ is true under $\nu$. If $x$ occurs freely in $A$ then (a) seems to coincide with this meaning. But it is stated clearly that $A$ is closed.

For example, take $A:=\forall x Rxx$, with $\cup=\mathbb{N}$ and $R:=\leq$.

What is the proper way to understand this? The expression $A_{a}^{x}$ seems to sometimes mean substitution of free variable for element of $\cup$ while others instantiation in $\cup$.
Thank you.

Pages 43-47[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: *Substitution* is a "syntactical" operation (see def): replace a free occurrence of a variable $x$ in a formula $A$ with a parameter $a$. Example with $A := (x >0)$, $A_a^x := (a >0)$. If no occurrence of $x$ is free in $A$, than $A_a^x=A$.

Comment: The *valuation* operation (as used by Smullyan) is a "semantical" operation that gives "meaning" to a formula. To "evaluate" formula $(x >0)$ in the domain $\mathbb N$ with a valuation $k(x)=3$ means to check the truth of statement $(3 > 0)$. The trick used by Smullyan is to use a domain $U$ (a *universe* of *individuals*) where we use the "objects" of $U$ as "names" for the objects themselves, i.e. as *constants* of the language. Usually, with $\mathbb N$ we use *numerals*: $\overline 3$ as names for *numbers*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denoting by $A$, Smullyan talks about a formula in a generic sense (atomic/compound, open/closed, parametric/non-parametric). So, for example, $A(a/x)$ —this is more widespread and preferable than Smullyan's notation— denotes the resultant formula obtained by substituting $a$ for every free occurrence of $x$ in $A$.
Thus, let $A$ be the closed formula $$(0<a<1)\rightarrow (a^{2}<a)$$ for some defined parameter $a$. Take notice that this is nothing but, with an abuse of notation for illustration, $$(0<[a/x]<1)\rightarrow ([a/x]^{2}<[a/x])$$

Hence, $A = A(a/x)$.

The same idea applies to the case parameters replaced by individual constants. In other words, Smullyan goes back and forth between two types exemplified by the following statements:

1. Socrates is mortal.
2. $\ldots$ is mortal, where '$\ldots$' is substituted by 'Socrates'.

Originally, the term *sentence* is used as an alternative for *closed formula*, because it does not contain any '$\ldots$' just as it is in natural language.

As a side note, quantifying over closed formulas, called *vacuous quantification*, is legitimate in the majority of logical systems.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It still puzzles me why Smullyan says $A$ is closed (i.e. it is a sentence) before stating (a). Wouldn't it make more sense if $x$ occurred freely in $A$? With $A$ closed (a) becomes a case of vacuous quantification.

Comment: I recon that this statement (p. 45) hints at his conceptual organisation of the matter: "Using our substitution operation, we can say that *x* has a free occurrence in *A* if for some parameter *a* (or equivalently for every parameter *a*) *A(a/x)* is distinct from *A*."